# Upgrading from a 3 wire rotary thermostat to a Electronic Digital

Tags: heating, thermostat, central-heating

[image]This is my first post so please be gentle. I currently have a Honeywell rotary thermostat (240V) 3 Wires plus earth.

1. Live in
2. Neutral (for the anticipator I believe)
3. Switched live out

I appreciate that I could swap this out and replace it with something like the SALUS RT500 2 wire system and just terminate/isolate the Neutral, But........
I was wondering if I could use something like this (Photo)

In this case could I use my Live and Neutral feed (originally terminals 1 and 2 on the old unit) and connect the switched live to L1 to supply the boiler
So that the new set up would be

- Live (1) Now to Terminal 4
- Neutral (2) Now to Terminal 3
- Switched Live (3) now to Terminal 1

The new thermostat has an internal Temp sensor with the option of an additional external.

Please feel free to offer any advice of shoot me down in proverbial flames. 
Thanks in advance 
Rod

Comment: Country or region (if in split voltage countries like Ecuador or Philippines)?  We don't really do the flames here, unless you're trying to burn houses down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is a 230v line voltage thermostat switching an electric resistive heater, that is virtually identical to USA 240V heaters and their line voltage thermostats.... I would imagine that, as with us, your choices of smart thermostat are limited.

You might borrow a Yankee  trick to use virtually all the smart 'stats on the market.  That is: use a **relay** to switch power to the heater.  The relay operates on small amounts of your thermostat's working voltage, e.g. 24VAC in the USA and don't quote me, 240VAC in the UK.  The smart 'stat does not know or care it is working a relay for electric heat, it just knows that when it calls for heat, heat comes on.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the device you pictured.

You might have to bridge 2 & 3 with a short wire loop if the terminals are not internally bridged. The manual would make this clear or you could test with a continuity tester.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would I actually need the 2nd Neutral return though if it's only pushing out the switched live. Admittedly It would be far simpler it I had the unit and could just bang a DVM across the terminals.  Just wondered if anyone had tried to do it like this

Comment: I would find it very surprising if  they provide line N and load N and didn't jumper them internally.  It is classically UK to provide all the terminations you will need, just look at your 8-screw ceiling roses!